# How to design a service Laravel for rating users?

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a service - a class for setting a user rating.

There are two models: User, Rate. Many-to-many relationship.

The rating creation method is described as follows:

```
function create(Order $order, User $user, User $user_rated, Rating $rating, $rate) {
  return OrderRating::create(["user_id" => $user->getId(), 'order_id' => $order->getId(), 'rating_id' => $rating->getId(), 'rate' => $rate]);
}
```

Where:

```
$order; // additional information for evaluation
$user; // who is rating
$user_rated; // who is rated
$rating; // rating model
$rate; //the rating itself from 1 to 5
```

I'm confused by the large number of parameters in the function.
There is also a temptation to pass only Request $request - an object to the create function:

```
function create(Request $request) {
  // do everything else
}
```

But in this case, the function becomes impersonal. On the other hand, I don't want to mess up the controller.

Comment: I think using `Request $request` is more ideal than using the instances, since you need is the id, well, assuming user_rated, rating, and order are IDs

Comment: From client I get data like this: [1: 5, 2: 5] where key id if of rating, and values are rate from 1 to 5. Only this data comes in Request

Comment: Typically, in a Controller method, if you see a large number of arguments, it's to match URL Parameters. Given the URL: `/order/{order}/user/{user}/rating/{rating}` (or `/order/1/user/1/rating/1` when compiled), each of the `{thing}` would translate to `(Order $order, User $user, Rating $rating)`. This can be converted to use `Request $request`, but typically, you'd use Query String parameters, like `?order=1&user=1&rating=1`, or POST data, then pull them via `$user = User::find($request->input('user')`, etc. Double check how this method is being used, then determine if you can change 

Comment: Yeah, you can remove the `User $user` since you said that it was the one who rating. You can just call it using `Auth::user() - for user instance` or `Auth::id() -> user id`

Answer (score 0):

Consider what's going to be sustainable long-term. For controller methods, it's usually best practice to work off of a `Request` passed as an arg or accessed via the helper function, `request()`. This is because you will often be sending your requests to your controller methods straight from your `web.php` or `api.php` routes files.

Knowing this, you'll have occasions where you'll want to handle controller logic differently based on what the request looks like (e.g. `request()->wantsJSON()`, etc.). If your method signature accepts a static number of arguments, you're more likely to lock yourself into an inflexible pattern. While it may not matter in the immediate, it will make adaptability more challenging down the road.

Comment: So, it is dilemma. I want to make service more business oriented to be not dependent by framework